# How to reduce query execution time using mango query in CouchDB?

Tags: couchdb

I am doing pagination of 15000 records using mango query in CouchDB, but as I skip the records in more numbers then the execution time is increasing.

Here is my query:

```
{
  "selector": {
    "name": {"$ne": "null"}
  },
  "fields": ["_id", "_rev", "name", "email" ],
  "sort": [{"name": "asc" }],
  "limit": 10,
  "skip": '.$skip.'
}
```

Here skip documents are dynamic depends upon the pagination number and as soon as the skip number increases the query execution time also get increase.

Answer (score 1):

CouchDB "Mango" queries that use the `$ne` (not equal) operator tend to suffer performance issues because of the way the indexing works. One solution is to create and index that *only contains documents where `name` does not equal `null` by using CouchDB's relative new *partial index* feature.

Partial indexes allow the database to be filtered at *index time*, so that the built index only contains documents that pass the filter test you specify. The index can then be used with a query at *query time* to further winnow the data set down.

An index is created by calling the `/db/_index` endpoint:

```
POST /db/_index HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 144
Host: localhost:5984

{
  "index": {
    "partial_filter_selector": {
      "name": {
        "$ne": "null"
      }
    },
    "fields": ["_id", "_rev", "name", "email"]
  },
  "ddoc": "mypartialindex",
  "type" : "json"
}
```

This creates an index where only documents whose `name` is not null are included. We can then specify this index at query time:

```
{
  "selector": { 
    "name": {
      "$ne": "null"
    }
  },
  "use_index": "mypartialindex"
}
```

In the above query, my `selector` is choosing all records, but the index it is accessing is already filtered. You may add additional clauses to the selector here to further filter the data at query time.

Partial indexing is described in the [CouchDB documentation here](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.1/api/database/find.html#partial-indexes) and [in this blog post](https://medium.com/ibm-watson-data-lab/creating-partial-cloudant-indexes-1ebf169c8e15).

Comment: Well, thanks for your brief reply, I have successfully created the partial index but when I make the request to fetch data then an error returns.

"The index specified with "use_index" is not useable for the query" This is the error

Comment: And I have a confusion regarding query after indexing. Suppose I have done indexing and I have 150 documents in my database then how would I fetch documents between 120 to 130 just like we do in RDBMS using lower and upper limits.

Comment: When querying the index, it's good practice to repeat the selector you specified in the `partial_filter_selector` step. I've updated the second code snippet in the answer to suit.